# I want to remove .deb package in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I installed `youtube-dl_2015.06.04.1-1~webupd8~trusty0_all.deb` in my system.

It is not properly installed and I want to remove this package from my system. I am using the command below to remove this package.

I am getting following error.

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge youtube-dl_2015.06.04.1-1~webupd8~trusty0_all.deb   
    dpkg: error: --purge needs a valid package name but 'youtube-dl_2015.06.04.1-1~webupd8~trusty0_all.deb' is not: illegal package name in specifier 'youtube-dl_2015.06.04.1-1~webupd8~trusty0_all.deb': character `~' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
```

I also tried with below command

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge youtube-dl
dpkg: error processing package youtube-dl (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 youtube-dl
```

How can I remove this?

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg -r <Package_name>`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel It is not strange. Just a long package version. All deb files have 2 underscores ;-)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - fairly standard - it is sourced from the webupd8 PPA (see article [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/command-line-video-download-tool.html))

Comment: @Pilot6 Oh, sorry, now I got it - was confused - I assumed the package is an alternative build of `youtube-dl` with a changed package name `youtube-dl_...` - I do not see deb file names often; and in my world, the underscore is by definition a name character... Learnded... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Removing of packages is done by a package name, not by file name.

You can remove it by

```
 sudo dpkg --purge youtube-dl
```

This command will also remove configuration files of that package.

Just to remove the package and leave configs, run

```
sudo dpkg -r youtube-dl
```

If you deleted some files of the package manually, you can get an error messaage

```
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should reinstall it before attempting a removal Errors were encountered while processing: youtube-dl
```

In this case re-install it again and then remove

```
 sudo dpkg -i youtube-dl_2015.06.04.1-1~webupd8~trusty0_all.deb
 sudo dpkg -r youtube-dl
```

***And in the future never delete any files installed by deb packages!***

This can break the whole system

Comment: Why not? If OP wants to purge with configs.

Comment: I gave both ways. But generally to completely remove "purge" is better.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried with both command,I am getting below  error  sudo dpkg --purge youtube-dl
[sudo] password for dharmendra: 
dpkg: error processing package youtube-dl (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 youtube-dl

Comment: Please add it to your question and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force <Package_name>
```

Then try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. To get the package name from the `.deb` file run:

```
dpkg --info file.deb | grep Package
```

It will output something like:

```
Package: packageName-x.y
```

This is the name of the package. To remove it:

```
dpkg -r packageName-x.y
```