# Uninstall multiple deb packages at a time

Tags: package-management, uninstall, deb

is there a way to remove multiple deb packages at a time. I have a little under a hundred deb packages. I went to the directory with all the deb files, and I ran the command below.

```
sudo dpkg -r *.deb
```

I got this error:

```
dpkg: error: you must specify packages by their own names, not by quoting the names of the files they come in
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there really no way to remove deb packages without doing it one at a time?

Comment: Never use * as a wildcard. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/210976/apt-get-remove-with-wildcard-removed-way-more-than-expected-why What you should do is a `find` and pipe the result to `dpkg`.

Comment: I don't think the problem here is multiple files - it's that `dpkg` expects *package names* not *file names* - see related [I want to remove .deb package in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635251/i-want-to-remove-deb-package-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -r` command is used to remove installed packages,

And looking at the format `.deb` it looks like you are just trying to delete `.deb` files

to delete those you just need to use the simple rm command

```
rm *.deb
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and straightforward.

Comment: But is this a solution? This only removes files, it does not uninstall any packages.

Comment: @ArturMeinild But it looks OP just wants to delete all the files ending with _.deb_ , to remove a package use command `apt remove <packageName>` or `dpkg -r <packageName>`

Comment: This removes all `.deb` files but does not remove the packages installed using these .deb files.

Answer (score 0):

"remove multiple deb packages at a time" litteraly means removing these `.deb` files. This is simply done using a `rm *.deb` command.

If, however, your real intent is to remove all packages that have been installed using these `.deb` files, then i does not work the way you think. `.deb` files only install packages, they are not used to remove them. Instead, packages installed in the system are removed by e.g. `apt remove <packagename>`.

Your `.deb` files still can be usefull to create a list of the packages they may have installed.

- If the file is named according to the conventions, the first part of the file name will tell you the name of the installed package.
- More reliable, however, is to obtain the package name using the `dpkg --info <packagename>` command.

This can be automated for multiple files using the standard shell tools, but allow me to leave this as your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You should use package names with `dpkg -r`, not `.deb` file names.

The error message is quite informative.